# join 2 list and convert into a tuple

Tags: python

I've this code below in the code section.

> I must return a list where all the functions in the second argument
>       have been applied to the elements of the first argument in a format type of a tuple
>   for instance for this 2 list

```
objs = [(1,2),[1,3,4,5,6,7],[0]]
funcs = [len,sum]
I must return #--> [(2, 3, <class 'tuple'>), (6, 26, <class 'list'>), (1, 0, <class 'list'>)]
```

> thank you if you can help

```
objs = [(1,2),[1,3,4,5,6,7],[0]]
funcs = [len,sum,type]


def calc_len(objs, funcs):
    t = []
    z = []
    for i in objs:
        print(i) # To check output
        z.append(i) # Create a list Z of "i"
        #print("Z : ", z)
        # Then I apply each function from the second list
        for j in funcs:
            if j==len:
                print("Lenght:",j(i))
            elif j==sum:
                print("Sum :" ,j(i))
            else:
                print("Type :",j(i))
            t.append(j(i))
 # How Turn that list into a tuple and add to list to return
        print (t)



print(calc_len(objs, funcs))
Should return #--> [(2, 3), (6, 26), (1, 0)]
```

Below the result

```
[358]: print(calc_len(objs, funcs))
(1, 2)
Z :  [(1, 2)]
Lenght: 2
Sum : 3
Type : <class 'tuple'>
[2, 3, <class 'tuple'>]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Z :  [(1, 2), [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
Lenght: 6
Sum : 26
Type : <class 'list'>
[2, 3, <class 'tuple'>, 6, 26, <class 'list'>]
[0]
Z :  [(1, 2), [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0]]
Lenght: 1
Sum : 0
Type : <class 'list'>
[2, 3, <class 'tuple'>, 6, 26, <class 'list'>, 1, 0, <class 'list'>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to apply each function to the arguments and build a tuple with the results.

```
result = [ tuple(f(x) for f in funcs) for x in objs ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objs = [(1,2),[1,3,4,5,6,7],[0]]
result =  [(len(item),sum(item),type(item)) for item in objs]
print (result)
```

output:

```
[(2, 3, <class 'tuple'>), (6, 26, <class 'list'>), (1, 0, <class 'list'>)]
```

.

```
objs = [(1,2),[1,3,4,5,6,7],[0]]
funcs = ['len','sum','type']

def calc_len(objs, funcs):
    result = []
    for item in objs:
        r = []
        for func in funcs:
            if func == 'len':
                r.append(len(item))
            if func == 'sum':
                r.append(sum(item))
            if func == 'type':
                r.append(type(item))
        result.append(tuple(r))
    return result

print(calc_len(objs, funcs))
```

output:

```
[(2, 3, <class 'tuple'>), (6, 26, <class 'list'>), (1, 0, <class 'list'>)]
```